# Button to delete current ListView Row in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am using data binding to populate a `ListView` from an SQLite DB. I would like the user to be able to press a Button and for the current row to be deleted.

Page1.xaml:

```
  <ListView x:Name="recentUserList" Margin="20,0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                            <Grid HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="3" Text="Delete" Clicked="BtnDelete_Clicked" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Page1.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
        base.OnAppearing();
        recentUserList.ItemsSource = App.Database.GetUserList();
}

private void BtnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var user = sender as User;
        recentUserList.Remove(user);
}
```

Database:

```
public List<User> GetUserList()
{
    return database.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM User;");
}
```

User.cs:

```
 public class User: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        private string userName;
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return userName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (userName!= value)
                {
                    userName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This results in the following error for `Remove` in `recentUserList.Remove(user);` in Page1.cs.

> Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'CollectionExtensions.Remove<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, TKey, out TValue)'

How can I make it so it is possible to click the button to delete the given `ListView` item/row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` object is of type `Button` not `User`, although it `BindingContext` property is of type `User` in this case:

```
private void BtnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var btn = sender as Button;
        var user = btn.BindingContext as User;
        //recentUserList.Remove(user);
}
```

Also `recentUserList` is a ui element (`ListView`) it does not have a `.Remove()` method. What you need to do is to bind it `ItemsSource` to an  `ObservableCollection` whic you will call the .Remove() method.

I highly invite you to read the [related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding)

Answer (score 1):

first use an `ObservableCollection`

```
ObservableCollection<User> users;

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
        base.OnAppearing();
        recentUserList.ItemsSource = users = new ObservableCollection<User>(App.Database.GetUserList());
}
```

then delete the `user` from the data source and the UI will udpate

```
private void BtnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var btn = sender as Button;
        var user = btn.BindingContext as User;
        users.Remove(user);
}
```